# Can't handle a dataframe with fastAPI : can't add a line in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, fastapi

I'm trying to learn fastAPI.
I have a dataframe and I want to collect data from this dataframe or add data in the dataframe

I can collect data from a dataframe (the GET(/) request  works).

But if I want to add a line and then collect data from the df, it dosen'twork.
(see my example with the GET(/test) request )

As such, i can't use a put request if I really want to add date to the dataframe (the put('/add') request doesn't work either).

I have a massage which said **"Internal Server Error"** and on VSCODe this is what i have
*

> df_marks = df_marks.append(new_line, ignore_index=True)
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df_marks' referenced before
> assignment

- 

```
import pandas as pd 
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Header
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
    

data = {'name': ['Somu', 'Kiku', 'Amol', 'Lini'],   'marks': ['A', "B", "C", "A"]}
df_marks = pd.DataFrame(data)


api = FastAPI(
    title='my_API' )

@api.get('/') def get_index():
    return df_marks.iloc[1,1]

@api.get('/test') def get_index():
    new_line = {'name':'Jo', 'physics':"A"}
    df_marks = df_marks.append(new_line, ignore_index=True)
    return df_marks.iloc[1,1]


@api.put('/add') def put_users():
    new_line = {'name':'Jo', 'physics':"A"}
    df_marks = df_marks.append(new_line, ignore_index=True)
    return df_marks.iloc[1,1]
```

WHat should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `global df_marks` as the first line of your request:

```
@api.get('/test') def get_index():
    global df_marks
    new_line = {'name':'Jo', 'physics':"A"}
    df_marks = df_marks.append(new_line, ignore_index=True)
    return df_marks.iloc[1,1]
```

When referencing non-local variables (like you are doing with df_marks, which lives outside your GET method), the interpreter assumes you mean the global variant but only if you are not setting the variable with the same name in the scope of the method.

The error demonstrates this:

```
df_marks = df_marks.append(new_line, ignore_index=True) 
# ---------^ This is the df_marks mentioned below in the error. 
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df_marks' referenced before assignment
```

You are setting the value of a new **local** variable named `df_marks` and the reference after that (the one with `.append`) is no longer pointing to the global version.

Comment: ok thank you, I'm new with python too.

if I don't want to use global, can I pass the df marks as an argument into the get Method (similarly as passing an argument into a function)? How can I do that?

Comment: You should close this question and open a new one, as that is a very different question (from “how do I solve this error” to “how do I do X in FastAPI”). But to give a pointer: look at app state in FastAPI, and how to access that using the Request object.